# Saving NSMutableDictionary to plist iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary, save

This has become very frustrating over the past day-and-a-bit-too-much: why doesn't this work?

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",kAllScoresUnorderedArray]];

 NSMutableDictionary *test = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [test setObject:@"bob" forKey:@"tmo"];

 [test writeToFile:path atomically: YES];
```

I have used it before, and it worked perfectly: is there something I am forgetting to add in my info.plist? That is the only thing I can think of.

Thank you for helping!

EDIT:
Maybe it has something to do with Xcode 4.5 and iOS6? It worked in 4.3/iOS5

Comment: When saying that it does not work, what exactly do you mean? Does it compile, does it crash, does it create a file?

Comment: Also, why are you using `stringWithFormat:` rather than `stringByAppendingPathExtension:`?

Comment: This part looks a little fishy: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",kAllScoresUnorderedArray]. What is in the kAllScoresUnorderedArray?

Comment: @Till no, it doesn't crash, it just keeps running as if the code wasn't there..

Comment: @PeterHosey I have never heard of the latter: I got the code from a tutorial, and it has worked for me before.

Comment: @Baglan kAllScoresUnorderedArray is #defined in the header as @"kasua"

Comment: Did you check if the plist was actually written to the filesystem? Also make sure you do plenty of debug output (`NSLog`) and/or tracing through this code line-by-line while using lldb's `po` feature.

Comment: Yes, I checked in the filesystem using an app called iExplorer... `NSLog`s do continue to print after the 'save' code has run... It's a mystery.

Comment: I put your code into a new project, and it worked fine (using Xcode 4.5 with the iPhone 6.0 simulator). If you log path, what does it give you?

Comment: Xcode 4.5 and iOS on the iPad logs the following: `/var/mobile/Applications/C1278BFF-F746-425E-A850-96BB168AACA3/Documents/kasua.plist` - I haven't got it as an iPhone project.
 On the iPad simulator I get `/Users/max/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/6004E690-970D-4177-8337-D544B7C9AD19/Documents/kasua.plist`

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and added this on top: `NSString *kAllScoresUnorderedArray = @"kasua";` It also worked for me, on Xcode 4.6.1 and iPhone 6.1 simulator. Are you sure if there isn't another issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the .plist file to your project?  If so, try this:

```
NSError *error;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",kAllScoresUnorderedArray]];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
            {
                NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kAllScoresUnorderedArray ofType:@"plist"];

                [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
            }

     NSMutableDictionary *test = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
     [test setObject:@"bob" forKey:@"tmo"];

     [test writeToFile:path atomically: YES];
```

If not, create the property list in your project.